# php mysql based on user input form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble using a checkbox to select one or multiple fields of data for PHP/AJAX to process and display. I have the PHP/AJAX working great on my `<select>`s but as soon as I try setting up the checkbox all hell breaks lose.

I also am very unsure on how to further prevent SQL injection on the site so if anyone could fill me in a little more about this I would GREATLY appreciate it! I read the link I was provided and just don't understand how `bid_param` or PDO works exactly.

The ajax script:
(I can't seem to insert the ajax/js so I'll leave a link to the live site)

[Link to Agent search page](http://www.healthbenefitsohio.com/advance.php)

My php page that displays the data:

```
<div id="bodyA">
    <h1>Find a Local OAHU Agent.</h1>
    <!-- This is where the data is placed. -->  
</div>
<div id="sideB">
    <div class="sideHeader">
        <em>Advanced Search</em>            
    </div>
    <form class="formC">
        <label for="last">Last Name</label><br />
        <select id="last" name="Last_Name" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php 
    include 'datalogin.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT Last_Name FROM `roster` ORDER BY Last_Name ASC;");
    echo '<option value="">' . 'Select an Agent' .'</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Last_Name'].'">'.$row['Last_Name'].'</option>';
    }
?>
        </select>
        <label for="company">Company</label><br />
        <select id="company" name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php 
    include 'datalogin.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM `roster` ORDER BY Company ASC;");
echo '<option value="">' . 'Select a Company' .'</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['Company'] == NULL) {
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Company'].'">'.$row['Company'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
        </select>
        <label for="WorkCity">City</label><br />
        <select id="WorkCity" name="WorkCity" onChange="showUser(this.value)" value="city">
<?php 
    include 'datalogin.php';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT WorkCity FROM `roster` ORDER BY WorkCity ASC;");
    echo '<option value="">' . 'Select a City' .'</option>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['WorkCity'].'">'.$row['WorkCity'].'</option>';
    }
?>
        </select>
        <label for="WorkZipCode">Zip Code</label><br />
        <select id="WorkZipCode" name="WorkZipCode" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php 
      include 'datalogin.php';

      $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT WorkZipCode FROM `roster` ORDER BY WorkZipCode + 0 ASC;");
      echo '<option value="">' . 'Select a Zip Code' .'</option>';
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['WorkZipCode'].'">'.$row['WorkZipCode'].'</option>';
      }
?>
        </select>
        <label for="agent">Agent Expertise</label><br />
        <label for="ancillary"><input type="checkbox" value="Ancillary" name="Ancillary[]" id="ancillary" />Ancillary</label><br />
        <label for="smallgroup"><input type="checkbox" value="Smallgroup" name="Smallgroup[]" id="smallgroup" />Small Group</label><br />
        <label for="largegroup"><input type="checkbox" value="LargeGroup" name="LargeGroup[]" id="largegroup" />Large Group</label><br />
        <label for="medicare"><input type="checkbox" value="Medicare" name="Medicare[]" id="medicare" />Medicare</label><br />
        <label for="longterm"><input type="checkbox" value="LongTerm" name="LongTerm[]" id="longterm" />Long Term Care</label><br />
        <label for="individual"><input type="checkbox" value="Individual" name="Individual[]" id="individual" />Individual Plan</label><br />
        <label for="tpa"><input type="checkbox" value="TPASelfInsured" name="TPASelfInsured[]" id="tpa" />TPA Self Insured</label><br />
        <label for="ppaca"><input type="checkbox" value="CertifiedForPPACA" name="CertifiedForPPACA[]" id="ppaca" />Certified for PPACA</label><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

My php page that pulls the info and places it into a container on the page:

```
    $q = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : false; // Returns results from user input

    include 'datalogin.php'; // PHP File to login credentials

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `roster` WHERE Company = '".$q."' OR Last_Name = '".$q."' OR WorkCity = '".$q."' OR WorkZipCode = '".$q."' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) // Connects to database or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    echo "<h1>" . "Find a Local OAHU Agent." . "</h1>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // Gets results from the database
                echo "<div class='agentcon'>" . "<span class='agentn'>" . "<strong>".$row['First_Name'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['Last_Name'] . "</strong>" . "</span>" . "<a href=mailto:".$row['Email'] . ">" . "<span class='email'>".$row['Email'] . "</span>" . "</a>" ."<div class='floathr'></div>";
                if ($row['Company'] == NULL) {
                    echo "<p>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<p>" . "<strong>" .$row['Company'] . "</strong>" . "<br>";
                }
                echo $row['WorkAddress1'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['WorkCity'] . "," . "&nbsp;" .$row['WorkStateProvince'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['WorkZipCode'] . "<br>";
                if ($row['Work_Phone'] !== NULL) {
                    echo "<strong>" . "Work" . "&nbsp;" . "</strong>" .$row['Work_Phone'] . "<br>";
                }
                if ($row['Fax'] !== NULL) {
                    echo "<strong>" . "Fax" . "&nbsp;" . "</strong>" .$row['Fax'] . "<br>";
                }
                echo "<strong>" . "Agent Expertise:" . "</strong>";
                if ($row['Ancillary'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "Ancillary" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['SmallGroup'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "Small Group" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['IndividualPlans'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "Individual Plans" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['LongTermCare'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "Long Term Care" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['Medicare'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "Medicare" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['LargeGroup'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "LargeGroup" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['TPASelfInsured'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "TPA Self Insured" . "/";
                }
                if ($row['CertifiedForPPACA'] == 1) {
                        echo "&nbsp;" . "Certified For PPACA";
                }
                echo "</p>" . "</div>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I appreciate any and all help on this topic! Any time I add the checkbox values to my php file it ends up displaying everyone in the database for all fields in the form.

I am also trying to prevent sql injection on this but how can a user do this if I don't have a field the user can input text into?

*EDIT* As of today I gave a try with using jQuery to activate the checkboxes and then call some AJAX.
Here is the script I wrote and it is pulling an agent, just not everyone that has that "expertise".

```
$('input').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            data: { value: 1},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#bodyA').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Before you write *any* more SQL code, you **must** read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and how to use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to properly insert values from `$_GET` into your queries without creating severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Yeah defiantly agree with that, you don't want people to gain unauthorized access from gaping holes like that.

Comment: Okay I am reading up on this page but like I said I am totally new to sql and even using a database in general. Mind giving me a slightly broken down explanation about bind_param?

Comment: RE: PHP, some bad practive in there as well. If you dont have anything to do in an `else` dont code one. Also if yuo have nothing to do in an `IF` but you do have something to do in an `else` then change the test in the `IF` so you dont have empty `IF` statements with an `ELSE`. It will make your code easier to read and understand and therefore easier to maintain in 6 months when YOU have to try and understand it again.

Comment: Hmm Okay I see what you mean with the  else statements but when I was using only an if statement and the field was empty it would include an empty row in the results. That's why I was using an empty if statement with the else statement to echo the result.

Comment: @JoshPowell Try `if ($row['Work_Phone'] !== NULL)`. that means NOT EQUAL

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! I remember reading about not equal on w3 schools but was a little unsure of when to use it. I pretty much taught myself, what I know, php based off my studies on w3 schools. heh At least once I finally take a php class in college I should have a better understanding.

Comment: @JoshPowell RE Your actual question. You are going to have to be more specific about what you are doing and what actual problems you are getting. the only solution to `all_hell_breaks_loose()` I believe is `Get_God()`.

Comment: Okay The first 4 fields for a user to search are just select fields that pull the required field from the database and inputs it as an option so I don't need to keep updating the list. The input checkbox fields are what's causing the problem for me. When you check one of them they would pull everyone from the database and also cause my select fields to do the same. Right now I have the checkbox fields using jquery to change the header so it still functions. I need them to function the same as the select fields do by pulling the data based on which one is checked and than posting it onto bodyA.

Comment: I don't know if this pertains to this situation but check boxes don't "appear" in the the $_POST/$_GET array if they are not check so it is best that you use isset() if not set.

Comment: I do use the isset() on my php page based on the users input: `$q = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : false;` I was also told to do something like this : `name="Medicare[]"` for the checkbox but it all ends up failing :/

Comment: If you want to be able to do a $_POST/$_GET on which checkboxes are checked, you'll have to name each of them the same (for example, name all of them "medicare[]") and then in PHP loop through them to get the values. Only the ones that are checked will be posted when you do a check on isset

Comment: Hmm very interesting, I am about to try this because all of them are named to their corresponding title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I DID IT!! Wohoo! I ended up just making a separate php page called expertise.php to process the checkboxs using jquery/ajax.

The jQuery that achieved this: (Thank god I went onto the jQuery website to look up functions!)

```
$('input').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "expertise.php",
            data: { value: 1},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#bodyA').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

The PHP page is the same as my process.php page except for the sql:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `roster` WHERE Ancillary = '1' AND SmallGroup = '1' AND CertifiedForPPACA = '1' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC";
```

If anyone would enlighten me more on making this better protected against sql injections, feel free to!

[Agent Search Page](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/advance.php)

Well I at least got both parts of the search working but a new problem has arose :p

Now in the sql I can use AND or OR, with AND it pulls only agents that have everyone of those expertise and with OR it seems to pull everyone. Any ideas?

Comment: Great job! That's close to what I was just about to update my answer with (going with an ajax approach). Was doing some final testing before I updated it but looks like you beat me to it!

Comment: @Brian Thanks a lot! I am super proud from the results for my first time using php. I still have a minor problem with the results I am getting though. Using AND in the sql gives me only the agents who has all of those fields and using OR gives me all agents, any ideas?

Comment: Well using AND, only results that meet every criteria will come back. Using OR allows for a much broader search, therefore more results. I'm guessing you are wondering which to use when for the checkbox values? If so (and I'm understanding it correctly), my original suggestion about separating them with commas should work but you would being using SQL's IN instead of =. Something like..."Ancillary IN ('Largegroup', 'Smallgroup') ORDER BY Last_Name ASC. Please note that I am in NO WAY a SQL expert and this is only a suggestion based on the information shared here.

Comment: Since you have figured out the answer to the main question here, you might want to start a new question regarding the SQL stuff as it would probably have more hits being a new question and you can add some SQL tags to it as well...just a thought though. :)

Comment: I will give your suggestion a try and see if that works. If it does not I'll make a new question based on my current state. :p Thank you so much for all your help mate! It really has helped me out a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example of something I recently worked on in which I needed to loop through multiple checkboxes and pass those values into a SQL statement. Although this example happens on a button click, hopefully its something along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish, or at least at start... :)

```
<?php
$array = array();
if (isset($_POST['medicare'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['medicare'] as $value) {
        array_push($array, $value);
    }
}
// this will return the value of each selected checkbox, separating each with a comma
$result = implode(",", $array);

// if you want to loop through each individually (for example pass each into a SQL statement)
foreach ($_POST['medicare'] as $value) {
    // Do your SQL here 
    // $value will be the value of each selected checkbox (Smallgroup, Largegroup, etc.)
    $sql = "insert into tablename(fieldname) values ('$value')"; // just an example
}
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="medicare[]" id="smallgroup" value="Smallgroup" />
<label for="smallgroup">Small Group</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="medicare[]" id="largegroup" value="Largegroup" />
<label for="largegroup">Large Group</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="medicare[]" id="medicare" value="Medicare" />
<label for="medicare">Medicare</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="medicare[]" id="individualplan" value="IndividualPlan" />
<label for="individualplan">Individual Plan</label>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" />
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of setting one variable, try setting a variable for each `select` control and putting your SQL statement in a `foreach` loop. I just tested this with some dummy data and didn't have any issues with it.

```
<?php
$lastname = (isset($_GET['Last_Name'])) ? $_GET['Last_Name'] : false;
$users = (isset($_GET['users'])) ? $_GET['users'] : false;
$workCity = (isset($_GET['WorkCity'])) ? $_GET['WorkCity'] : false;
$WorkZipCode = (isset($_GET['WorkZipCode'])) ? $_GET['WorkZipCode'] : false;

foreach ($_GET['medicare'] as $value) {
    //echo $value;
    $sql="SELECT * FROM roster WHERE Company = '$users' OR Last_Name = '$lastname' OR WorkCity = '$workCity' OR WorkZipCode = '$WorkZipCode' OR Ancillary = '$value' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC";
}
...continue as you were...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly I have been trying this out and it ends up doing nothing and not even giving me any errors so I'm not to sure what to do. I don't know why this one is so difficult heh, using the select fields was so easy and did not make me want to pull my hair out.

Comment: Did you try to echo the results to see if anything is coming back?

Comment: Yeah I did and I was expecting it to at least show something or error. Here is a link to the live site that I am working on, [link](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/advance.php). The first four `select` fields work just fine but as soon as I trying to fiddle with the Agent Expertise area the entire script goes crazy. Bare with me as the structure design is not by me but everything else is :}

Comment: How are you detecting when a checkbox is checked/unchecked? It looks like something is happening because if I change any of the 4 selects with Ancillary checked, then uncheck Ancillary, the page updates. If I try the same steps with any of the other checkboxes the page doesn't update...You need to verify that every checkbox is being detected when checked/unchecked. I see you are doing an onChange for the selects, but are you using jQuery and making an ajax call to detect the checkboxes?

Comment: I assigned the checkbox each their own value so when one is clicked it tells the database to fetch said value. I tried an .onChange for it which would refresh that div but still not pull the info, maybe I should just use some jquery for the checkboxs? I would much rather use a `input` checkbox instead but when I add any of the agent expertise to the sql, for `input` and `select` tags, it pulls everything or select things.

Comment: When the sql is $sql="SELECT * FROM `roster` WHERE Company = '".$q."' OR Last_Name = '".$q."' OR WorkCity = '".$q."' OR WorkZipCode = '".$q."' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC"; it works great but as soon as I do $sql="SELECT * FROM `roster` WHERE Company = '".$q."' OR Last_Name = '".$q."' OR WorkCity = '".$q."' OR WorkZipCode = '".$q."' OR Ancillary = '".$q."' ORDER BY Last_Name ASC"; is when it get's all messed up. I just want this to function and checkboxs would be ideal for this data but it causes so many problems. :p

Comment: See my update. I think you just need to assign a variable for each select and put the SQL in a loop so you're passing the correct values in each time.

Comment: Thank you a bunch for the reply and I will try this out as soon as I get to work tomorrow! I'm really hoping this works!

Comment: Thanks for all the help you have offered but I tried this out today and keep getting errors. Where exactly would I put this? on the process file or the advance page? I did try both but like I said I am very new to php so it is most likely an error on my part.